# Group policy allowing single user control of an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, vpc

How can I create a policy that will allow a single user in a group to create an ec2 instance in a particular VPC and AZ?

I need it to also be destroyable by the same user or destroyed when idle for more than 24 hours.

Comment: It's not a bad question. But you can try to go to [http://serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com). You'll get better target audience

Answer (score 1):

You can't. What you can do, however, is script the logic yourself to provide equivalent functionality. A good starting point would be to google AWS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via IAM policies nor other configurations.

You would have to **write your own application with this logic**, which would launch the instance on the user's behalf and then terminate it later (although that depends on your definition of 'when idle'). The user would interact with this application when they want to launch the instance, rather than interacting directly with AWS.

To be more specific:

- It **is** possible to limit the number of EC2 instances that an AWS Account can have running simultaneously (the default is 20)
- It **is not** possible to limit the number of instances a single user may launch. Either they have permissions to launch an instance with certain attributes, or they don't, but this cannot be limited by whether/what instances are already running.

Some ways you could create a **self-terminating instance**:

- A CloudWatch Alarm could terminate an instance when CPU or Network drops below a certain level for a period of time (eg when Network Out is below 10KB over a half-our period).
- A script on the instance itself could decide when to Shutdown the instance. If the instance is launched with **Shutdown Behaviour** set to **Terminate**, then shutting down the instance from within the instance will cause it to terminate.
- You could create an application that regularly looks at running instances and terminates them 24 hours after being launched. This could be triggered by a Scheduled Task (Windows) or `cron` job (Linux).
- A variation on the previous option is to add a **Tag** to the instance to indicate when to terminate it. An application could regularly check the tag to determine which instances to terminate.